# jQuery click .animation trigger

Tags: jquery

How to trigger that reverse animation with the user click any where on the page BUT the white dialog box div?(Please see jfiddle the see what im talking about, click on top left img to see the animation) Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hBb9L/7/

Thank You For All The Future Help!

```
$("#e").click(function() {
  //done
$("#re").animate({
  "margin-top": "104px"
}, 800);
$("#ret").animate({
  "margin-top": "104px"
}, 800);
$(".popu").animate({
     "margin-top": "-102px"
 }, 800);
 $("#s").show(200);
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should place a photo to click the photo!